# url rewriting a query string

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, query-string

I want to mod-rewrite url and i am just wondering how do i rewrite my url of querystring type

```
http://localhost/folder/index.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

into

```
http://localhost/folder/value1/value2/value3
```

I have this htaccess file please tell me if it correct

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/(w+)/(w+)/(w+)$ /index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [nc]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your DOCUMENT_ROOT's .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !param1= [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ $1/index.php?param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i am not able to run since it is going in infinite redirection loop. Is just entering http://localhost/folder/value1/value2/value3 will show me the result? And i forgot to tel that my param1 is global variable i am passing the value directly through url  while other param are taken from an array.

Comment: Please check my updated answer (I added a RewriteCond to prevent looping). And yes you need to enter `http://localhost/folder/value1/value2/value3` to test it. Above URL will load `http://localhost/folder/index.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3` internally.