# rewriting url with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string, clean-urls

in continuation to [what i asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745174/get-params-with-clean-url-in-multi-hosting-environment) i want to auto rewriting of below url

```
http://testsite.com/siterootb/sample-page.php?bbi=value1&bbl=value2
```

to

```
http://testsite.com/siterootb/sample-page/value1/value2
```

my `htaccess` now looks like

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost%{REQUEST_URI}%1? [R=301,L]

###########################################################################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/siterootb/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/siterootb/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1.php?bbi=$2&bbl=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

i have gone through [URL Rewriting - Query String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271352/url-rewriting-query-string), [url rewriting a query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470670/url-rewriting-a-query-string), [wordpress how to remove ? from the url using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721074/wordpress-how-to-remove-from-the-url-using-htaccess) and many more whichever i got from `[query-string] [.htaccess]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /siterootb/([^.]+)\.php\?bbi=([^&\ ]+)&bbl=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /siterootb/%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]
```

The reason you must match against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is because you want to literally match against what is requested, not the URI. The URI changes as rules are being applied so you're going to match against a change that another rule has made if you match against the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable.

Comment: something's not working..it appends too many values for %2 and %3 to the URI..unable to find why..

Comment: the output of this rule comes out like this `http://localhost/siterootb/sample-page/value1/value2/value1/value2/.../?bbi=value1&bbl=value2`

Comment: @RishiKalia Sorry, I forgot a `?` after the `/siterootb/%1/%2/%3`